# URI->new("longerThan248Chars://bla") throws "Identifier too long at (eval 1) line 1"

Tags: perl, uri, runtime-error

I'm canonicalizing URLs using Perl (v. 5.12) and I've noticed that the Perl program started crashing with the message "Identifier too long at (eval 1) line 1.". Through experiments I've found out that the `URI` constructor throws error when the scheme part of the URL exceeds 248 symbols:

```
$ perl -e 'use URI; my $uri = URI->new("a" x 248 . "://bla");'
Identifier too long at (eval 1) line 1.
```

Why is this happening?
How to prevent this?

Comment: guessing, may be an inbuilt feature to prevent XSS vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 4):

[URI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI) is looking for a module named

```
URI::aaaaaaaaaa
```

by doing what boils down to

```
eval "require URI::aaaaaaaaaa;"
```

Perl thinks your crazy.

```
>perl -e"eval 'require '.('a' x 500); die $@;"
Identifier too long at (eval 1) line 1.
```

---

The best solution would be to [submit a patch](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=URI) to the author to add

```
return if length($scheme) > 200;
```

to `implementor`.

---

In the mean time, you can either catch the error using

```
my $uri = eval { URI->new( ... ) };
```

or you can precheck for that condition:

```
$uri_string =~ /^${URI::scheme_re}:/
```